# php dynamic replacement with a std object

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

How can I make a dynamic replacement with a std object?
I can't get how to use $1 in this case :(
See below.

```
$lang->custom_name = "Me";
$lang->custom_email = "Me@me";

$html = "hello {{custom_name}} with  {{custom_email}} ";    

$html = preg_replace("/{{(custom_.*)}}/", $lang->{'$1'} , $html);
```

Comment: What is ```$1```?

Comment: (custom_.*)  the stdClass is like $lang->custom_variablename

Comment: How does the original string look like?

Comment: added some more code to clarify

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `preg_replace`, use `preg_replace_callback` as it'll make it possible to use any mechanism you want to supply a replacement value.

```
// create stdClass 
$obj = (object) ['custom_foo' => 'foo-repl', 'custom_bar' => 'bar-repl'];
$html = "{{custom_foo}} {{custom_bar}}";

$res = preg_replace_callback("#{{(custom_.*?)}}#", function ($m) use ($obj) {
  // m (match) contains the complete match in [0] and the sub pattern in [1].
  return $obj->{$m[1]};
}, $html);

var_dump($res); // string(17) "foo-repl bar-repl"
```

If you want to use this for handling localization values, there are other, always made libraries that handle both the definition files, translate tools, etc. Look into `gettext` and friends (and there are probably other modern alternatives in other frameworks).

Comment: I was trying a loop with matches of preg_match but I like this more :) Thanks!

Comment: @rosia Also make sure you're using `.*?` to avoid making the pattern greedy.